# Is it possible to write a script that automatically triggers some function within a Google Sheets add-on?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers, google-apps-script-add-on

I'm using some Google Sheets add-on which pulls information from API databases, and it has both a free subscription and paid subscriptions which add many additional abilities which I don't really need, plus one I do need which is automatic scheduled data-pulls.

The product page even explains why the scheduling is limited in some ways due to how Google itself provides timing for automatic triggering.

So my question is, is it possible to write a separate Apps Script that simply tells an available add-on when to run?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: It's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that you can trigger an add-on to run using Apps Script. The easiest solution, and the right thing to do, would be to pay the add-on developer the subscription fee they request for the scheduling feature.

Comment: While that might be reasonable in some situations, I think that subscribing for several dozens of dollars per month for basically the ability to tell Google (not the company who made the add-on) to tell its own servers to re-run a the add-on is too expensive. I would have definitely paid if there was a reasonable one-time purchase, although as I said beyond the features already available in the free version I only need to automatic triggering

Comment: This one specifically is called API Connector, although if this option is possible in principle I suppose it shouldn't matter what add-on is in question.